# Erro ORA-12571 encountedred em Serviço do Windows

Tags: c#, windows, services

Tenho um sistema em C# rodando como serviço do windows, com Windows Server 2012R2.

Eventualmente quando o serviço tenta se comunicar com o banco de dados(para realizar uma consulta ou fazer um insert, por exemplo) a comunicação entre o servidor windows e o host onde está rodando o banco de dados "caí" e então é gerado o erro oracle ORA-12571.

*Já sabemos que isto não é um problema no banco de dados, mas na comunicação entre os host.*

Para resolver, simplesmente rodo novamente o serviço e tudo acontece sem problemas.

O pior é que o registro de eventos do windows não captura nada que possa nos ajudar ou dá uma pista sobre o problema.

Se precisarem de mais detalhes, é só pedir!

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de implementar um exception handling no ponto onde o erro ocorre e tentar uma reconexão?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu `sqlnet.ora`

Procure por --> `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)`

Altere para --> `SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)`

Comment: Prezado, muito obrigado pelo retorno, vou testar neste momento e retorno o resultado assim que souber.

Comment: Obrigado Otto! Até o momento não tivemos mais ocorrências deste erro :)